# Groupby two columns in pandas, and perform operations over totals for each group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

The code below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./filename.csv', header='infer').dropna()

df.groupby(['category_code','event_type']).event_type.count().head(20)
```

Returns the following table:

[image]

How can I obtain, for all the sub groups under event_type that have both "purchase" and "view", the ratio between the total of "purchase" and the total of "view"?

In this specific case, for instance, I need a function that returns:

1/57

1/232

3/249

Eventually, I will need to plot such result.

I have been trying for a day, without success. I am still new to pandas, and I searched across every possible forum without finding anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time please consider adding a sample of your data as text instead of as an image. It helps us testing..

Anyway, in your case you can combine different dataframe methods, such as `groupby`, as you have already done, and `pivot_table`. I used this data just as an example:

```
  category_code event_type
0             A   purchase
1             A       view
2             B       view
3             B       view
4             C       view
5             D   purchase
6             D       view
7             D       view
```

You can create a new column from your `groupby`

```
df['event_count'] = df.groupby(['category_code', 'event_type'])\
                      .event_type.transform('count')
```

Then create a `pivot_table`

```
my_table = df.pivot_table(values='event_count', 
                          index='category_code', 
                          columns='event_type', 
                          fill_value=0)
```

Then, finally, you can calculate the `purchase_ratio` directly:

```
my_table['purchase_ratio'] = my_table['purchase'] / my_table['view']
```

Which results in the following DataFrame:

```
event_type     purchase  view  purchase_ratio
category_code                                
A                     1     1             1.0
B                     0     2             0.0
C                     0     1             0.0
D                     1     2             0.5
```

Comment: You are right, I just didn't know how to insert a sample of my training dataset, which is large several GBs (I am new to pandas)...
BTW, your solution works perfectly! Thank you!!!